# Firebase Authentication with popup - allow only registered user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to create website where I have separate Sign In and Sign Up form. I also want to have Google authentication with Firebase.

I've implemented it like this both on sign in and sign up page:
`await FIREBASE_AUTH.signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider);`

But this code will always create new user.

What I would like to do is to block creating new user on sign in page, only log them in if user already exists (e.g. as I require terms of use consent on sign up page, but I don't want to require it on sign up page - it would be quite weird)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "if the user already exists".  Are you saying that you only want to allow users to sign in to email/password accounts that you create ahead of time?  Note that you can't create Google auth'd accounts ahead of time - the user has to effectively submit their own account creation.

Comment: Hi. What I mean is that if users clicks "sign in with google" on my sign in site (in contrary to sign up site) I want to show them "this account is not registered" if they didn't sign up with google before. Reason for is that I have all constent checkboxes only on sign up website, not on sign in (it would be weird)

Comment: How would your site know if the user was previously registered if the user didn't go through the standard sign in process to verify their prior registration?  And if that process didn't allow the user to create an account, how would any user be able to create an account?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in Firebase Authentication to prevent users from signing up, while still allowing them to sign in if they're already created. The reason for this is that Firebase Authentication merely focuses on allowing users to **authenticate** themselves, so to prove who they are by providing credentials. What they can then do in your app is known as authorization, and is up to you to implement in your front-end application code, back-end application code, and server-side security rules.

For example, if you use one of Firebase's databases (Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database), you'll typically maintain a list of approved user's in that list (either their email or their UID). Then before granting the user access to specific screens in your app or data in your database, you check if the users exists in that list. If not, you don't grant access to the screen or data.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see an issue here, when a user uses google auth when they already have an account it will create a new account with their in some cases new data he might have changed in his google account.
In case your users hold other data in your database I'm pretty sure there's a google auth API for that issue.